# ScalaTest AsyncFunSuiteLike multiple asserts

Tags: scala, future, scalatest

I am rewriting tests that used to test an Akka actor that responded with a String, right now, we use a function that returns a `Future[String]`. So rewriting the tests using AsyncFunSuiteLike.

Currently I'm looking at a test that has to assert multiple Futures, but I don't seem to understand how to achieve it with AsyncFunSuiteLike.

My test looks as follows:

```
test("Error responses") {

    NanoHTTPD.Response.Status.values().filter(status => status.getRequestStatus >= 400).map {
      status => {
        val statusCode = status.getRequestStatus
        httpService.setStatusCode(status)
        val responseBody = s"Request failed with status $status"
        httpService.setResponseContent(responseBody)
        val errorMessage = s"Error response (${status.getRequestStatus}): $responseBody"

        myobject.request("123456").map {
          resp => assert(resp === "....")
        }
      }
    }

}
```

But I am getting an error `type missmatch. Expected: Future[Assertion] actual: List[Future[scalatest.Assertion]]`

Any idea on how can I achieve multiple assertions within a single test like that?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

ScalaTest [asynchronous testing](http://www.scalatest.org/user_guide/async_testing) expects the test body to return `Future[Assertion]`. Now your test body returns `List[Future[Assertion]]]` because

```
NanoHTTPD.Response.Status.values() ... // Returns List
  ...
    myobject.request("123456").map(resp => assert(resp === "....")} // Returns Future[Assertion]
  ...
}
```

We can convert `List[Future[T]]` to `Future[List[T]]` using

```
Future.sequence(listOfFutures)
```

and, we can convert `List[Assertion]` to `Assertion` using

```
assert(listOfAssertions.forall(_ == Succeeded))
```

Putting this together we get

```
Future.sequence {
  NanoHTTPD.Response.Status.values().filter(status => status.getRequestStatus >= 400).map {
    status => {
      val statusCode = status.getRequestStatus
      httpService.setStatusCode(status)
      val responseBody = s"Request failed with status $status"
      httpService.setResponseContent(responseBody)
      val errorMessage = s"Error response (${status.getRequestStatus}): $responseBody"

      myobject.request("123456").map {
        resp => assert(resp === "....")
      }
    }
  }
}.map(listOfAssertions => assert(listOfAssertions.forall(_ == Succeeded)))
```

Comment: Thanks Mario. I am facing an issue tho. When asserting, the errorMessages set on the val do not match the ones in the resp. I am guessing this is due to the asynchronous of the test. I always get the last errorMessage in the resp, since when the async test runs, the NanoHTTPD is always set to the last values set. Is there any way to solve this? (without using Await)